# Where to initialize something ONCE in a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController subclass and I'm trying to figure out what to override such that I can run some initialization code only once per object instance.

The `viewDidLoad` method might seem like the obvious answer, but the problem is that `viewDidLoad` may run more than once if the controller resets the view due to a memory warning.  The `initWithNibName:bundle:`, `init`, and `initWithCoder:` methods also seem like       good choices, but which one to override?  The `awakeFromNib` method is another consideration, but that doesn't seem to be executed in my view controller.

Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably still use viewDidLoad, but inside use a static boolean to see if you've been there already.

```
static BOOL didInitialize = NO;
if (didInitialize == YES)
    return;

didInitialize = YES;
/* initialize my stuff */
```

Comment: I think my question wasn't clear.  I meant my object instances, but I suppose the same approach could be used with an object variable.

Answer (score 5):

UIViewControllers's designated initializer, the method that all other initializers are supposed to call, is `-initWithNibName:bundle:`. If you want to initialize something when your view controller is created, override that method.

`-viewDidLoad` is meant for any setup that depends on the controller's views. As you point out, that method may run more than once because the views may be loaded more than once. `-awakeFromNib` won't help unless your view controller itself exists in a nib, and even then it only makes sense if the thing that you're initializing depends on other objects in that same nib.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `-initWithFrame:` isn't a method of UIViewController so I don't think that would work.  Perhaps you meant `initWithNibName:bundle:`?

Comment: Doh. You're right, of course... I was thinking of UIView, not UIViewController. I'll fix the post.

Comment: This answer is correct. Only one init method should run your initialization code, and the other init methods should call that init method.

Answer (score 2):

What about `+(void)initialize` ? That's a class initializer that iOS calls for you, once, for the class, as I understand it.

Comment: Remember to check `if (self == [MyViewController class])`.

Comment: Does +(void)initialize get called when the object is unpacked from the nib?  If not, the required initialization may not happen correctly.

Comment: If it's loading from a nib, you can implement `-(void)awakeFromNib` to do one-time setup for the reconstituted object. But this is not class initialization; this is per-instance of a nib object one-time setup. Different.

Comment: That would work for my class instances, but not for my object instances.  I'll reword the question to make it clearer.